# Etat HTTP 404 - /icescrum

Tags: tomcat

I want to install iceScrum R6.14.11 PRO ,on windows 7, 64 bit .
Im using Tomcat as a host , after using this command "java -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar icescrum.jar"  and checking the suggested URL from cmd http://192.168.1.100:8080/icescrum

I had this error , did I missed any step?

**Etat HTTP 404 - /icescrum**

**type Rapport d''état**

**message /icescrum**

**description La ressource demandée n''est pas disponible.**

**Apache Tomcat/7.0.56**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are good chances that you are trying to run iceScrum with Java 8 whereas iceScrum is only compatible with Java 7 for the moment. Java 8 is supported in the next major iceScrum version (7), which is currently in online beta only.

You can check which version of Java is used by entering the following in the command line:

```
java -version
```

If the output indicates that you are using Java 8 then you can download and install Java 7 from the Oracle website: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html (pick Server JRE (Java SE Runtime Environment) 7u80).

Several versions of Java can cohabit on the same machine, you just need to ensure that the `java` binary used in the command to start iceScrum is the one from Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

check if the port 8080 is accessible and not used by other program.

Comment: This is not an answer and it should have been posted as a comment. That's why I gave the minus 1.

Comment: hello, it is my first comment in stackoverflow , i did not know the rules, anyway for your problem: if you launch ""java -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar icescrum.jar" you dont need tomcat to be installed you just need java, so if tomcat is running it will occupy the port 8080, you have to stop tomcat (or unistall it ) than run :java -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar icescrum.jar", i had similar problem and that was the solution, thanks for -1 and good luck